# Magento Backend Payment method (PayPal)

Tags: magento-1.8, paypal, paypal-payments-pro, paypal-pro

Is there any module to take payments via PayPal from Magento admin. Currently Paypal does not seem to support payments from admin?
Are there any other options? We do not have merchant account so Sage pay might not be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Magento Admin supports adding an order and typing in the customers card details using PayPal, as long as you have upgraded your PayPal account to a Website Payments Pro.

This would mean you can take an order over the phone and type the customers card details directly into Magento admin and process their order.
All by using the PayPal functionality that was shipped with your Magento, no need to install 3rd party apps.

Upgrading your Standard PayPal to a PayPal Payments Pro account would seem like the simplest solution. ( also , it's cheaper than SagePay )

Comment: www.paypal.com/website-payment-pro

Comment: Thanks you very much. I will try the same and mark it as Resolved soon.